# CakePHP: Date field with default values

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2.1 and have a date field to get a users date of birth:

e.g.

```
echo $this->Form->input('Profile.dob', array('label' => 'Date of Birth'
                                        , 'dateFormat' => 'DMY'
                                        , 'empty' => array('DATE','MONTH','YEAR')
                                        , 'minYear' => date('Y') - 110
                                        , 'maxYear' => date('Y') - 0));
```

As you can see I have tried to set the default values using an array, however it just makes them all have a default value of DATE. How do I get it so that each of the dropdowns has the correct value?

Comment: Looking at the [CakePHP source](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/form-helper#l-2168) it doesn't appear to be possible without hacking the source. You could manipulate the markup returned and replace the placeholders before outputting it though.

Comment: The empty option label is not the same as the default value. And it's possible to set both separate default values and empty labels for each of the date/datetime select lists. The default values are set using the `value` parameter. Separate empty labels can be set by using `FormHelper::day()`, `FormHelper::month()`, and `FormHelper::year()` separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack and quite ugly, but since the `empty` option doesn't appear to support multiple values it's probably the easiest solution - unless you want to rewrite the whole `dateTime()` function. `str_replace` unfortunately doesn't allow limiting the number of replacements, which is why we have to resort to `preg_replace`.

```
$placeholder = '[RandomStringWhichDoesNotAppearInTheMarkup]';

$out = $this->Form->input('Profile.dob', array('label' => 'Date of Birth'
                                            , 'dateFormat' => 'DMY'
                                            , 'empty' => $placeholder
                                            , 'minYear' => date('Y') - 110
                                            , 'maxYear' => date('Y') - 0));

$escapedPlaceholder = preg_quote($placeholder, '/');
$out = preg_replace("/$escapedPlaceholder/", 'DATE', $out, 1);
$out = preg_replace("/$escapedPlaceholder/", 'MONTH', $out, 1);
$out = preg_replace("/$escapedPlaceholder/", 'YEAR', $out, 1);

echo $out;
```

Answer (score 5):

The feature you want is now [implemented](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/99813e97b3f3acab0a479371c21d6f9d22dbccdb) and will be available in next release. Currently you can checkout the master branch from github to get this patch. Check the test cases in linked commit for usage example. If you are currently using cakephp 2.1, read the 2.1 to 2.2 migration guide on the manual as the master branch is the 2.2 dev branch.

Comment: Definitely the best option if your are after getting rid of ugly hacks in your code

Answer (score 4):

I have checked this It will give same output which is required :
This code will generate same dropdown box with given default value and the post data will be same :

```
echo $this->Form->day('Profile.dob', array('empty'=>'Day'));
echo $this->Form->month('Profile.dob', array('empty'=>'Month'));
echo $this->Form->year('Profile.dob', 1950, date('Y'),array('empty'=>'Year'));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
echo $form->input('date', array(
'type'  => 'date',
'label' => 'Date',
'empty' => TRUE,
'minYear' => 2000,
'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
'maxYear' => date('Y'),
'minYear' => date('Y') - 10
# default order m/d/y

));
?>
```

Its woking like charm

**EDIT**:-(You can do this with simple jquery code)
In case you want customised date empty value
ADD this jquery script in you header with jquery.js included.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     

        // var valid=true;

        jQuery(document).ready( function() {

            $("#dateDay option:first").text('DAY');
            $("#dateMonth option:first").text('MONTH');
            $("#dateYear option:first").text('YEAR');


        });




</script>
```

[image]

change id #dateDay, #dateMonth, #dateYear with your option field id....You can customise this making it work for every cakephp-date field.

Comment: I interpreted OPs question to be if it was possible to add default *prompt* values (*empty* values in this case) - different for each dropdown in this case.

Comment: you can do this by simple jquery infact... @mogelbrod    :)

Comment: Yes it's indeed possible, but using client side JS to fix a shortcoming in CakePHP might not always be the preferred choice :)

Comment: Since the `empty` placeholder string will be inserted as an option in each (all three of them) dropdown you can just replace the placeholder texts one by one (using `preg_replace`) with the text you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('birth_dt', array( 'label' => 'Date of birth'
        , 'dateFormat' => 'DMY'
        , 'minYear' => date('Y') - 70
        , 'maxYear' => date('Y') - 18 ));
?>
```

//OR

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->year('Profile.dob', date('Y') - 100, date('Y') - 13, array('empty' => "YEAR"));
echo $this->Form->month('Profile.dob', array('empty' => "MONTH"));
echo $this->Form->day('Profile.dob', array('empty' => 'DAY'));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it like this

```
echo $this->Form->dateTime('dob', 'DMY','', array('value'=>'1987-02-12','empty'=>false,'label'=>'','minYear'=>date('Y')-60,'maxYear'=>date('Y')-15));
```

'value' attribute has been added after 2.0 api of cakephp and 'selected'  is remove

2.0 updates
$selected parameter removed

The $selected parameter was removed from several methods in FormHelper. All methods now support a $attributes['value'] key now which should be used in place of $selected. This change simplifies the FormHelper methods, reducing the number of arguments, and reduces the duplication that $selected created. The effected methods are:

```
FormHelper::select()
FormHelper::dateTime()
FormHelper::year()
FormHelper::month()
FormHelper::day()
FormHelper::hour()
FormHelper::minute()
FormHelper::meridian()
```